# Unable to run Android Espresso tests. The project uses Hilt Dependency Injection and Navigation Components

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, android-espresso, dagger-hilt

I am trying to run the following Espresso test. I have Android Hilt dependency injection setup in my project and its working well in the application but am facing issues running UI tests.

I also have a project library which is using Hilt aswell.

Getting the following Exception:

```
Process: com.muddassir.myapp, PID: 15570
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/test/internal/platform/tracker/UsageTracker;
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6952)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:272)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2055)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8019)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.test.internal.platform.tracker.UsageTracker" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.mock.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.muddassir.myapp.test-sXVdfWq9tpbgNg9sbalPuAase.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.cs.stackoverflow-hHsBjEoBRyEmFRYwawGgqA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.cs.stackoverflow.test-sXVdfWq9tpbgNg9sbalPuA==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.cs.stackoverflow-hHsBjEoBRyEmFRYwawGgqA==/lib/arm, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
```

My test is as follows

```
package com.muddassir.myapp.ui.activity


import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder
import androidx.test.espresso.Espresso.onView
import androidx.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.*
import androidx.test.espresso.contrib.RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition
import androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.*
import androidx.test.filters.LargeTest
import androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner
import com.cs.stackoverflow.R
import dagger.hilt.android.testing.HiltAndroidRule
import dagger.hilt.android.testing.HiltAndroidTest
import org.hamcrest.Description
import org.hamcrest.Matcher
import org.hamcrest.Matchers.allOf
import org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

@LargeTest
@HiltAndroidTest
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner::class)
class ParameterTest {
    @get:Rule()
    var hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

    @get:Rule
    val activityRule = AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner(MainActivity::class.java)

    @Before
    fun init() {
        hiltRule.inject()
    }

    @Test
    fun parameterTest() {
        val recyclerView = onView(
            allOf(
                withId(R.id.questionsRv),
                childAtPosition(
                    withId(R.id.swipeToRefreshL),
                    0
                )
            )
        )
        recyclerView.perform(actionOnItemAtPosition<ViewHolder>(0, click()))
    }

    private fun childAtPosition(
        parentMatcher: Matcher<View>, position: Int
    ): Matcher<View> {

        return object : TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
            override fun describeTo(description: Description) {
                description.appendText("Child at position $position in parent ")
                parentMatcher.describeTo(description)
            }

            public override fun matchesSafely(view: View): Boolean {
                val parent = view.parent
                return parent is ViewGroup && parentMatcher.matches(parent)
                        && view == parent.getChildAt(position)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

lib/build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "com.cs.myapp_lib.HiltTestRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'

    def test_version = "1.3.1-alpha03"


    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0'

    // Retrofit
    def retrofit = "2.9.0"
    api "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit"
    api "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit"
    api "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:$retrofit"
    api "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:$retrofit"

    api 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:5.0.0-alpha.2'

    // Utilities
    api 'com.github.muddassir235:kmacros:1.10'

    def room = "2.2.6"
    api "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room"
    api "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room"

    // Dependency Injection through HILT
    def hilt_version = '2.31.2-alpha'
    api "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"


    // ...with Kotlin.
    kaptAndroidTest "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"

    def hilt_view_models = '1.0.0-alpha03'
    api "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:$hilt_view_models"
    kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:$hilt_view_models"

    // Libraries for tests

    kaptAndroidTest "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.3.1-alpha03'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0-alpha03'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.4.0-alpha03'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.4.0-alpha03'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-accessibility:3.4.0-alpha03'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-web:3.4.0-alpha03'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso.idling:idling-concurrent:3.4.0-alpha03'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.1-alpha03'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:core-ktx:$test_version"
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.3.1-alpha03'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.4.0-alpha03'
    androidTestImplementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:$hilt_version"
}
```

app/build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.cs.stackoverflow"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "com.muddassir.myapp.HiltTestRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':stackoverflow_lib')

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'


    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'


    // Dependency Injection through HILT
    def hilt_version = '2.31.2-alpha'
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"



    // ...with Kotlin.
    kaptAndroidTest "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"
    // ...with Java.
//    androidTestAnnotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28-alpha'


    def hilt_view_models = '1.0.0-alpha03'
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:$hilt_view_models"
    kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:$hilt_view_models"

    // Libraries for tests

    kaptAndroidTest "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"

    def fragment_version = '1.3.0-rc02'
    debugImplementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:$fragment_version"

    def test_version = "1.3.1-alpha03"

    def nav_version = '2.3.3'

    // Kotlin
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:$nav_version"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0-alpha03'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.4.0-alpha03'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-accessibility:3.4.0-alpha03'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-web:3.4.0-alpha03'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso.idling:idling-concurrent:3.4.0-alpha03'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.1-alpha03'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.3.1-alpha03'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.4.0-alpha03'
    androidTestImplementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:$hilt_version"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:core-ktx:$test_version"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-testing:$nav_version"
}
```

Project build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.30"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.28-alpha'
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.3"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: post your di code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the stable versions of the test runner and rules `1.3.0` or `1.3.1-alpha02`

```groovy
implementation "androidx.test:runner:1.3.0"
implementation "androidx.test:rules:1.3.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same.
If we use hilt test with custom runner class then we got issues in runner class.

```
testInstrumentationRunner "com.example.testing.HiltTestRunner"
```

so while using hilt, the manual test cases would be better.